# Is there a tool to test if a date-time is in a given range?

Tags: cron, date, command

I need to develop a script to test if "now" (e.g. the output of `date`) is in a given range. For now, this range is expected to be a list of days of month (e.g. `10,11,12,13,21,22,23`). And I could code that myself.

However, I would prefer to use existing tools instead of coding myself. And I expect the range requiredment to evolve, most probably to restrict on some hours of the day. And maybe also on day-of-week. So I thought about cron syntax that we all know.

**Question:** is there a tool to check of a given date-time is "inside" a cron syntax range or the like (tools that that don't use cron syntax could be ok too)?

Comment: As an aside, remember that if you're checking for hour ranges, then `<= 18` is actually true until the second before **7**pm.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need to test when "now" is? What larger system does this form a part of?

Comment: @MJ713 We have some process that are triggered and monitored by a central system of the company (that we, as a team, don't managed). But updating it is a slow process, so we plan to having it call more frequently than necessary and select with our code what flow we execute and when. So we can update it ourselves through our CI/CD.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible way is to use Epoch time which is seconds from 01.01.1970 00:00.

Firs generate now date and time:

```
CDATE=$(date +%s)
```

then generate two other dates:

```
F1DATE=$(date -d "11:02 Feb 14 1999" +%s)
F2DATE=$(date -d "12:20 Feb 14 2024" +%s)
```

and then compare if `CDATE` is between `F1DATE` and `F2DATE`:

```
if [ "$CDATE -gt "$F1DATE" ] && [ "$CDATE" -lt "$F2DATE" ]
then # do the job
fi
```

Comment: Of course, if the two dates were entered by a fallible user, then the code should first perform a set of sanity checks - are both dates in the future; are both dates the same; which date is earlier and which is later so the `-gt`/`-ge` and `-lt`/`-le` tests can be applied to the appropriate dates.

Comment: @SottoVoce, the only thing we should know which date is early, which is late. And I suppose OP have this information.

Comment: thanks for the answer, it can be useful. But implementing the time selection my-self is not what I am looking for. My question is more: is there some standard linux tool that can "filter" or "query" if a date is in a date range/list? Specifically on "day-of-month", then maybe on "hour", and "day-of-week" would be nice. Or I can make the conversion myself and use something like `in_range 3 "1,5,18"` &| `in_range 15 12-18`?

Comment: @Juh_, I do not think so. But you can create such a script. BTW day of week and day of month have specific relation in cron, read more about this.